# Testing convergence/divergence of $\sum {(-1)^n \frac{1}{\ln(n)+(-1)^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been stuck on this problem and would like some help.

**What I tried**:

I firstly checked for absolute convergence:

$$\frac{1}{\ln(n)+(-1)^n} > \frac{1}{\ln(n)+\ln(n)} = \frac{1}{2\ln(n)} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Therefore the series does not converge absolutely.

Then I tried checking with the alternating series test, but got stuck on it.

Comment: Divergent because $x_{2n}+x_{2n+1}\sim-\frac2{\ln^2(2n)}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n) +(-1)^n}= \sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n) +(-1)^n}\frac{\ln(n) -(-1)^n}{\ln(n) -(-1)^n}\\=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^n\ln(n)}{\ln^2(n) - 1}- \sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{\ln^2(n) - 1}$$